# Serve http (port 80) and https (port 443) on same VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, https, virtualhost

I need to setup my VirtualHost on Apache to serve on both http and https (using standard ports)

If I enable the SSL Engine (as per below) - I get an error when on port 80.

The reason is, parts of the site need to be SSL but other parts don't. How can I go about serving both http + https on the site?

Here is my virtual host file....

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mysite.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mysite/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

     #SSL STUFF...
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/crts/mysite.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/crts/mysite.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/crts/DigiCertCA.crt


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't do this in one virtual host, because Apache needs to know which one's going to talk SSL and which one isn't (sidenote: nginx doesn't have this problem, you can tell it which listen directives relate to SSL; one of the many reasons I love it).

The way I manage this in Apache is to put all my non-SSL-related configuration into a separate file, and then have the two vhosts configured next to each other, each including the site-specific configuration file inside the vhost stanza, like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.12:80>
    Include /etc/apache2/sites/example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.12:443>
    SSLEngine On
    # etc
    Include /etc/apache2/sites/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems like an issue in Apache vHost, but it does the job without having to repeat configuration.

```
SSLCertificateFile /srv/.ssl/self/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/.ssl/self/server.pem

# REQUIRED
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/badhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.www
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's really weird, but exists!

Comment: This worked as well as you might expect from such a kludge — almost, but not quite! I found that Apache 2.4.10 sets the SERVER_PORT environment variable to 443 instead of using the port on which the request came in (80 or 443 depending). <IMAGINARY_PARAGRAPH_BREAK>
Pity, as I was hoping to be able to use this, as I really wanted to keep one file per virtual host.  
<IMAGINARY_PARAGRAPH_BREAK>
Also, you will need a ServerName directive inside the top <VirtualHost> otherwise it will gobble up requests by mistake. Set it to ServerName badhost.bad or something.

Comment: @DanielBeardsmore: I've just tested this with 2.4.18 from RH Software collections, and that seems to be due to the default of `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort Off`. If you set that to on, you seem to get the actual port used. (Funnily enough, I had to leave off the `SSLEngine On` in my doubly-used vhost and got port 80 as the default.)

Comment: @DanielBeardsmore: FWIW, `%{HTTPS}` will also be set correctly, but `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` isn't (always `http`). I'd feel silly putting in a feature request for a `UseCanonicalRequestScheme` directive, though.