# Apache2 conditional section based on port

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, sni, conditional

I don't know much about if statements in apache configuration, and I'm wondering if I can have a section of the configuration applied only if the request is received on a certain port.

In short, this is about SSL. I have name based virtual hosts, I can make a configuration for port 80, then duplicate it all for port 443, and add the relevant SSL configurations.

But this seems redundant. I was wondering if i can have something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
```

and then I can put:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile ...
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
SSLCACertificateFile ...
</IfModule>
```

inside an if statement that checks if connection is on port 443... or is such thing impossible? the server supports SNI, and I don't have any worries from non-SNI compliant browsers.

Comment: Why don't you define two virtual hosts, one on port 80 and one on port 443?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do now... I was just wondering if there's a less redundant way of doing it

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/303744/serve-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-on-same-virtualhost?rq=1

this answered my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, starting from Apache 2.4, you can use

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    # HTTPS-specific configuration here
</If>
```

in your configuration file.

Many other expressions inside the `<If "expression">` bracket are also supported, e.g. actually checking for a specific port, as you suggested. For more details see the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if).

However, keep in mind that some directives will not work within an `<If>` clause. Check for the allowed contexts of a directive, where `<If>` counts as a `directory` context (like `<Directory>`).

Comment: That's a bunch... but doesn't work with the directives for SSL: SSLEngline, SSLCertificateKeyFile, etc doesn't work inside such an If statement