# apache2: bulk redirect all vhosts to https, non-www

Tags: ssl, https, apache2

I have one Apache server with many VirtualHosts in various conf files. I thought I could define a blanket rule to redirect all traffic to all of those hosts to HTTPS and non-www urls.

Unfortunately, the configuration below (which I have in my `000-default.conf` file) only partially works. It works for urls that start with http://www.domain, https://domain (no www) and https://www.domain. It does not work for those that start with http://domain. Apache throws a 403 Forbidden (no access to / on this server).

As a *bonus*, the redirects also add an extra trailing slash that I'd like removed.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.?(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NC]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it. Took me a while to understand `RewriteRule`s syntax as well as that I cannot use `RedirectMatch` (which Apache recommends) in this case.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias www.*
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blaap.be/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blaap.be/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blaap.be/chain.pem

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)*(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)*(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't duplicate configuration for vHosts you can try to setup this in this way as described here: [Serve http (port 80) and https (port 443) on same VirtualHost](https://serverfault.com/questions/303744/serve-http-port-80-and-https-port-443-on-same-virtualhost)